# How to install Hibernate 5.2 in Eclipse Neon via Including Jar files?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I checked all Articles regarding inclusion of Jar files as follow -

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

But, some of the Jar files are not present in the Hibernate 5.2. Please do tell me which Jars to include. Should I include all Jar in the Required folder?

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of searching the net for "getting started hibernate eclipse linux" etc., I came across these set of instructions:
1. Open Eclipse.
2. Help->Eclipse Marketplace...
3. Type "Jboss Tools" in search box and press "Go".
4. Scroll down the result list and press "JBoss Tools some.ver.sion.Final"
5. Clicl "Install"
6. Check "Hibernate Tools" and "Confirm".
continue with the installation.

After the installation is done, I could start working.  While working I came across a few missing .jar files.  Eace time I had that problem, I googled theMissingJarFile jar (with no version number. for example, if I needed commons-collections4-4.1.jar I googled "commons-collections jar" and used the newest version I found) and added the jar file to the build path: right click on package->properties->Java Build Path->add External Jars.

I know this doesn't answer exactly your question, but it should sure solve your problem.
Good luck!

Comment: This is the new way of getting things done. But, like we used in version 3.X +, we imported the libraries.